# How to get packets statistics by port

Tags: wireshark

Is there a better way to get port statistics, such as stat by source port, or destination port?

for example to get results like below:

```
  --------------------------------
  | Src/Dst Port | Packets Count |
  | -----------------------------|
  |   22         | 100           |
  | -----------------------------|
  |   80         | 200           |
  |------------------------------|
  |   8080       | 300           |
  | -----------------------------|
```

I have checked wireshark's Statistics menu, and tshark command, but still don't know how to get the results I want.

Comment: What statistics are you looking for then that neither Wireshark nor tshark currently provide?

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask my question very clearly, I just want to get statistics information by port, for example to get results like below: 22(port), 123(number of packets); 80, 234; 8080, 345;

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to directly get this summary information from either Wireshark or `tshark`, but you can probably write a script to do it.

Here's one such script that may help you get started:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check usage
if (( ${#} < 2 )) ; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <file> <type> ... where type is udp or tcp"
        exit 1
fi

# Sanity check if the file specified actually exists or not
stat ${1} &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "File ${1} doesn't exist"
        exit 2
fi

# Validate the type
if [ "${2}" != "udp" -a "${2}" != "tcp" ] ; then
        echo "Invalid type ${2}.  Specify either udp or tcp."
        exit 3
fi

echo "Src/Dst Port | Packets Count"
tshark -nq -r ${1} -z endpoints,${2} | grep "^[1-9]" | tr -s ' ' | cut -s -d ' ' -f 2,3 | sort -n | gawk '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}'
```

Comment: If you want the output sorted by packet counts instead of by port, you can pipe the output of that script to "`sort -nk2`".

Comment: @Christoper Maynard, this script is exactly what I want. Thanks so much!